# How to Encrypt a n byte string with a n byte encryption result using Rijndael encryption C#

Tags: c#

I'm having a issue. This Encrypts my name perfectly. My name comes in as 4 long so the name might come in as "John" but then it Encrypts it as abcasdlkj123908=! (something like that) is there a way I can have it encrypt something instead like w124 that is the same length of the initial variable string it encrpyted? Also what if the name comes in as Darryl and is 6 long ? I need to deal with that too

```
public string EncryptAName(string someName)
    {
        Rijndael rinj = new RijndaelManaged();
        string encryptionKey = "HERPDERP";
        rinj.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        rinj.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        rinj.KeySize = 0x80;    // Decimal: 128
        rinj.BlockSize = 0x80;
        byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptionKey);
        byte[] encryptionKeyBytes = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
        int passwordBytesLength = passwordBytes.Length;

        if (passwordBytesLength > encryptionKeyBytes.Length)
        {
            passwordBytesLength = encryptionKeyBytes.Length;
        }

        Array.Copy(passwordBytes, encryptionKeyBytes, passwordBytesLength);

        rinj.Key = encryptionKeyBytes;
        rinj.IV = encryptionKeyBytes;

        ICryptoTransform ict = rinj.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] someNameByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(someName);
        someName = Convert.ToBase64String(ict.TransformFinalBlock(someNameByte, 0, someNameByte.Length));

        return someName;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think there is way to safely encrypt it to the same size string. But, you can achieve this just by XOR with your key in cycle to encode, and XOR again to decode. It CAN be hacked if length of key is less than length of input string, but well, better than nothing.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Do you need to encode it into something readable, or simple byte array will do?

Comment: I just need to have the "encrypted" version of the text the same length as the original text so that it can fit in my database column

Comment: so like : Original: "John" Encrypted: "zhMa" something like that

Comment: There is a decision: "need to have the "encrypted" version of the text the same length as the original text" vs security. Using well accepted encryption methods correctly will provide security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind encoding, you can do it just by XOR ing your string bytes with some very big key (which is greater by length). Small will do too, but it will be less secure:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = "Daniel";
        var key = new byte[] {5, 6};
        //encode
        var res = CycleXor(input, key);

        Debug.Assert(input.Length == res.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(res);
        //decode
        res = CycleXor(res, key);
    }

    private static string CycleXor(string input, byte[] key)
    {
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(CycleXor(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input), key));
    }

    private static byte[] CycleXor(byte[] input, byte[] key)
    {
        if(input == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
        if(key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
        if (input.Length == 0 || key.Length == 0)
            return input;

        int idx = 0;
        byte[] result = new byte[input.Length];
        while (idx<input.Length)
        {
            result[idx] = (byte)(input[idx] ^ key[idx % key.Length]);
            idx++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): "*Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.*"

Comment: I think, that author really meant is not security, but security through obscurity. So, it is protection against basic amateurs, but not from one who really wants to attack.